# Android Google sign-in gets DEVELOPER_ERROR (10)

Tags: android, google-signin

There are lot of online gotchas and SO questions on this topic and I pretty much read through lots of them, but this error still persists.

What have I done so far:

- Created both debug and release signing config
- Created Web and 2x Android credentials in Google Developer console
- Ensured that Android credentials in GDC have appropriate SHA-1 hashes and correct package name
- SDK uses ClientID of Web credentials

The app is still in development phase and hasn't been published to Play Store. Few days ago, we changed both `package name` and and `ApplicationID`. I made sure that have package name change mirrored to my credentials in GDC.

I am positive that login was ok until few days ago (possible linked to package name change).

Can you please suggest any other troubleshooting steps?

Comment: As a problem solving method and not and Android/Google method I would suggest clearing all caches, initializing your development environment (reboot, etc)... basically a clean start. Somewhere, something is caching something... Also, logoff from all Google/Android accounts, etc...trust this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue couple of days ago and I would like to offer a retrospective to anyone else who might stumble upon this.

Disclaimer: If I had read the docs more carefully, I would have spotted the issue.

What I knew:

- Both Facebook and Google sign-in worked from emulator
- Both worked when I launched app on a device via USB
- Both worked when I deployed locally build APK to a phone

Still, none worked when app was downloaded by `Internal tester` group from `Play store`.

I tried generating hash via `keytool` both for my `release` and `debug` key, but that did not seem to click.

Finally, after days of debugging, I have found what was wrong: Forget about your local (`debug`/`release`) keys and use the one that `Play Store` provided. You will find this one in `Release Management` section.

### For Google sign-in:

In your Google Developer Console, create a new credential where you will input a SHA-1 from Play Store

### For Facebook sign-in:

Get the SHA-1 and convert it to Base64. I used this tool: http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php. Then, input the base64 payload into your Facebook application.

Hope someone will find this at least a bit useful.